# Do the spawn chunks stay loaded across dimensions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do the spawn chunks stay loaded across dimensions?

If I'm in the Nether or The End for examples, do farms in the spawn chunks stay running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do stay loaded. But unfortunately farms will not work.

> All entity updates and block entity ticks in a dimension **are no longer processed 15 seconds after the last player leaves the dimension**. Thus, while the spawn chunks remain loaded, most activity ceases when no players are in the Overworld.

Source, [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/el/wiki/Spawn_chunk#Spawn_chunks_and_other_dimensions).